Modifying a vector already added to a vector of vectors in c++
Its been some time since I have coded in C++, and want to know how vector of vectors work in C++.
So, I have a vector of vector vec, and I have added a vector temp to it. Now I modify temp and add it again to vec, (as given in the code snippet). I can see that both the earlier version of temp and newer version of temp are added and are different, even though I modified the same temp vector.
Input
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> vec;
    vector<int> temp;

    temp.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(temp);

    temp.push_back(2);
    vec.push_back(temp);

    temp.pop_back();
    vec.push_back(temp);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "vec size: " << vec.size() << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i){
        for(int j=0; j<vec[i].size(); ++j){
            cout << vec[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

Output
vec size: 3
1 
1 2 
1 

My question is, when I add temp to vec, does c++ create a new copy vector of temp and insert it to vec? and performs this action everytime one adds temp to vec
PS: If I do the same operation with an ArrayList replacing vector in java, I get temp inserted thrice, but the values in vec is the latest value of temp, meaning that the modified latest temp is printed out, unlike c++
Java Output
List size: 3
1 
1 
1 

Thanks,

I'd think the Java behaviour is far more surprising, why'd you expect that there are hidden references everywhere, except if it's fundamental types? In C++, nothing is a reference unless you say so, which you didn't.

But, isn't pass by references in c++ come into picture once we pass the vec to some other function? Yeah Java was expected by me, as I am aware that in Java it is pass by reference and hence any modification will be reflected.

I am adding a vector to a vector of vectors in C++, so does that create a new vector and copy the values, as is evident in the example?

in java you never get your hands on the actual objects, you only get references, while in C++ you can choose

"Its been some time since I have coded in C++" ... it has always been like that

std::vector never stores references. How arguments are passed is irrelevant to that. Yes, std::vector always copies (or moves).

"pass by reference" vs "pass by value" is not "reference semantics" vs "value semantics". They are related, but not the same. This is about the latter.

C++ and Java are fundamentally different in spite of their similar look of syntax. If you use one as model to write code in the other it will be a mess.

Got it. "std::vector never stores references. How arguments are passed is irrelevant to that. Yes, std::vector always copies (or moves)". I was looking for this

Yes, that is true

Note: even though you compare to Java, the question really is only about C++. I wouldn't tag as Java and ArrayList.

Java passes everything by value, and references are a kind of value in Java. Java's "references" are fundamentally different from the "references" of C++. (Beyond the "curly braces and semicolons" syntax, Java and C++ are very different languages.)
